# Search algorithm for an expensive boolean function

Tags: optimization, search-algorithms, binary-search

I have the following problem. We have a boolean function $f$ that is expensive to compute for a given input. We need to find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $f(n)$ is true. We don't know anything about $f$, i.e., there could be multiple inputs that produce true. We only know that $n < M$, where $M$ is some maximum limit.

Obviously we could search for $n$ one step at a time starting from $1$, but this is expensive. Is there a better algorithm?

I tried implementing a nested binary search, but it was very slow for some inputs. The idea is to run binary search between $1$ and $M$. Say we get some answer $n'$ then we know that $n < n'$. So now I run a binary search between $1$ and $n'-1$. I repeat this process until I find the smallest answer from all the binary searches. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct search is in fact the best possible algorithm.

To know for sure that $n$ is the answer, it is necessary to know all the values $f(1), \dotsc, f(n)$. Using the direct search, upon reaching $n$, those values will have been obtained, and no other values of $f$ will have been obtained.